# How to pass closure with argument as argument and execute it?

Tags: swift, function, closures

Initializer of class `A` takes an optional closure as argument:

```
class A {
   var closure: ()?

   init(closure: closure()?) {
      self.closure = closure
      self.closure()
   }
}
```

I want to pass a function with an argument as the closure:

```
class B {
    let a = A(closure: action(1)) // This throws the error: Cannot convert value of type '()' to expected argument type '(() -> Void)?'

    func action(_ i: Int) {
       //...
    }
}
```

Class `A` should execute the closure `action` with argument `i`.

I am not sure about how to write this correctly, see error in code comment above. What has to be changed?

Comment: First of, that's not a function type, it's a void optional. Not making too much sense, but anyways. The word you're looking for is partially applied functions.

Comment: @ValentinRadu "The word you're looking for is partially applied functions" No it isn't.

Comment: @matt care to explain please? you have a partially applied function with all arguments partially applied. Many languages allow this, including Swift. `func (a:Int)() {}`. If using this has sense or not, that's a different question.

Comment: @matt I know semantically it doesn't fit in. That's not partial anymore. Still, it's using the same language feature. Think of the last parameter being void, which also invokes the function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please make your "what-you-have-now" code error free.

Assuming your class `A` like this:

```
class A {
    typealias ClosureType = ()->Void

    var closure: ClosureType?

    init(closure: ClosureType?) {
        self.closure = closure
        //`closure` would be used later.
    }

    //To use the closure in class A
    func someMethod() {
        //call the closure
        self.closure?()
    }
}
```

With `A` given above, you need to rewrite your class `B` as:

```
class B {
    private(set) var a: A!
    init() {
        //initialize all instance properties till here
        a = A(closure: {[weak self] in self?.action(1)})
    }

    func action(i: Int) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I execute the closure in class `A`? Neither `self.closure` nor `self.closure?()` seems to work.

Comment: `self.closure?()` should work. Where have you put that code?

Comment: My bad, i forgot to set `self.closure = closure`. Wrote it in the code example here but forgot it in my original code :-|

Comment: @Manuel , my old code makes circular reference. Check the edited code please.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that `closure()?` is not a *type*. And `()?` is a type, but it is probably not the type you want.

If you want `var closure` to have as its value a certain kind of function, you need to use the type of that function in the declaration, e.g.

```
var closure: (Int) -> Void
```

Similarly, if you want `init(closure:)` to take as its parameter a certain kind of function, you need to use the type of that function in the declaration, e.g.

```
init(closure: (Int) -> Void) {
```

Comment: So actually the argument is not an `Int` but a custom `enum`. Is there a way around if I don't want to declare the enum in class A and class B?

Comment: The enum must have a name, so use that name where I used Int. A type is a type.

Comment: matt: my apologies to high-jack you here (off-topic), but I'm beat: if you have the time, do you have any comment/explanation to my comment of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38336982/is-there-a-simple-way-to-test-if-you-match-one-of-a-set-of-enumerations#comment64091487_38336982), regarding what I believed to be equivalence between `case ...` pattern matching in `switch` statements vs. pattern matching using `if case ...` (I could post a separate question but it would be very close to a rip-off of the question I commented on).

Answer (score 3):

## Types as Parameters

In Swift, every object has a type. For example, `Int`, `String`, etc. are likely all types you are extremely familiar with.

So when you declare a function, the explicit type (or sometimes protocols) of any parameters should be specified.

```
func swallowInt(number: Int) {}
```

## Compound Types

Swift also has a concept of compound types. One example of this is Tuples. A Tuple is just a collection of other types.

```
let httpStatusCode: (Int, String) = (404, "Not Found")
```

A function could easily take a tuple as its argument:

```
func swallowStatusCode(statusCode: (Int, String)) {}
```

Another compound type is the function type. A function type consists of a tuple of parameters and a return type. So the `swallowInt` function from above would have the following function type: `(Int) -> Void`. Similarly, a function taking in an `Int` and a `String` and returning a `Bool` would have the following type: `(Int, String) -> Bool`.

## Function Types As Parameters

So we can use these concepts to re-write function A:

```
class A {
    var closure: (() -> Void)?

    init(closure: (() -> Void)?) {
        self.closure = closure
        self.closure()
    }
}
```

Passing an argument would then just be:

```
func foo(closure: (Int) -> Void) {
    // Execute the closure
    closure(1)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do what I think you're attempting is with the following code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let _  = A.init(){Void in self.action(2)}
    }

    func action(i: Int) {
        print(i)
    }
}


class A: NSObject {
    var closure : ()?

    init(closure: (()->Void)? = nil) {
        // Notice how this is executed before the  closure
        print("1")
        // Make sure closure isn't nil
        self.closure = closure?()
    }
}
```